# How to check if user is able to scroll vertically with Javascript if scrollbars are hidden?

Tags: javascript, scroll, scrollbar, vertical-scrolling

If scrollbars are hidden with CSS, how can I check if a user **is able** to vertically scroll with vanilla Javascript? Thanks.

Comment: You listen on the scroll event and check if a element on the page has shifted it's place.